# Java String - How to get chars until and after space

Tags: java, string

I'm load to variable string using:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
x = scanner.nextLine();
```

String always looks like: `"Random Example"`. I want to grab first word (before space) for one variable and second word (after space) to next one variable. Can someone show me example?

Comment: use `scanner.next()`

Comment: I could help you without using Scanner.I am not pretty used to Scanner Class.

Comment: I think there is something like a delimiter which could be useful in this case.And the default delimiter is supposed to be space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input obtained from scanning the input stream can be split based on the space character.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = scanner.nextLine();
    String array[] =x.split(" ");
```

In this way, the words are stored in array.

Answer (score 2):

You can get split a `String` using `.split(String s)` and put it in a `String[]`

```
String editMe;
Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
editMe = user_input.nextLine();
String[] edit1 = editMe.split(" ");
```

If you would like to see the values in the `System` you can use

```
int i =0;
for(String s:edit1)
{
    System.out.println(s);
    i++;
}
```

See more information on the `String` variable and how to use it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).